# ASPNET Core - Erro 500 ao fazer post em um método que retorna uma Partialview com só um objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, partialview

Eu tenho um método na minha controller chamado de `ListagemTarefasEmDesenvolvimento()` que me retorna uma `PartialView`. Porém, quando eu chamo esse método via ajax, o servidor me retorna um erro de estatus `500`.

Abaixo tem a minha controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ListagemTarefasEmDesenvolvimento()
        {
            var idUser = Int32.Parse(User.FindFirst("IdUsuario")?.Value);

            var obj = _tarefaContext.getTarefaEmDesenvolvimentoByIdUsuario(idUser).Result;
            
            var retorno = PartialView("_Em", obj);
            return retorno;
        }
```

O método `getTarefaEmDesenvolvimentoByIdUsuario()`, retorna somente um objeto. (não retorna lista).

Esse é a minha PartialView

```html
    @model RKMES.Models.Tarefa
    <h6>Em Desenvolvimento</h6>
    <div class="panel panel-body panel-shadow border-top-verde overlayEmDesenvolvimento" style="padding:16px;padding-bottom:0; background-color:#ffffff">
    
        <div data-id="@Model.Id" class="row panel-shadow containerTarefasAFazer" style="margin-bottom:18px;padding:12px">
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span style="font-size:16px"><strong>@Model.Nome</strong></span><br />
                    <span><strong>Atividade: </strong>@Model.Atividade.Nome</span><br />
                    <span><strong>Tempo previsto: </strong>@Model.HorasPrevisto</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a style="float:right" onclick="PausarTarefa(@Model.Id)" class="btn btn-pausar btn-icon btn-rounded">
                            <i class="icon-pause2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a style="float:right" onclick="FinalizaTarefa(@Model.Id)" class="btn btn-roxo btn-icon btn-rounded">
                            <i class="icon-checkmark3"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Algumas curiosidades:

- Se eu fizer o método `getTarefaEmDesenvolvimentoByIdUsuario()` retornar
  uma lista de objetos, e eu fizer um ajuste na view, tudo funciona
  normalmente.
- Pelo que vi em uns dos métodos construtores de `PartialView()`, ele
  espera um objeto como segundo parâmetro, então em teoria, o que eu
  fiz deve funcionar normalmente, mas eu recebo erro
  `500`.

Alguem sabe me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Faça o debug e veja qual é o erro 500... só essa informação não é o suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

**O erro ocorre por falta de validação de algum dos argumentos.**

Considere que se o erro é 500 o defeito não está na chamada desse endpoint.

A família de erros 500 referem-se à erros do lado do desenvolvedor, como por exemplo a falta de validação de nulo ocasionando um ArgumentNullException. O que o seu código realmente deveria fazer quando `User.FindFirst("IdUsuario")?.Value` retornar nulo?

Apenas como medida de teste, sugiro adicionar um tratamento de erro retornando a mensagem do erro interno. Isso facilitará seu diagnóstico.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ListagemTarefasEmDesenvolvimento()
{
    try
    {
        var idUser = Int32.Parse(User.FindFirst("IdUsuario")?.Value);
        var obj = _tarefaContext.getTarefaEmDesenvolvimentoByIdUsuario(idUser).Result;
        var retorno = PartialView("_Em", obj);

        return retorno;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var retorno = Content(ex.Message);
        retorno.StatusCode = 500;
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Na sequência faça uma chamada para esse endpoint através do Swagger ou Postman para ver a mensagem do erro.